# Delay displaying of page until everything is loaded

Tags: php, jquery, html, image

I have a page that has a lot going on, and when it finishes loading it looks fine, but I would like for it to load all of the images, etc, then display the page?  Might be another way around this.

http://www.randykrohn.com/gallery/pictures.php?EventID=279

Here is the code for the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/Primary.dwt.php" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Dragboats.com - Photo Gallery -</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/CSSMenuWriter/cssmw/menu.js"></script>
<link href="../includes/CSSMenuWriter/cssmw/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/includes/CSSMenuWriter/cssmw/menu_ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css" media="all">
<!--
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #FEFD8F;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/images/main_back.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

h1 {
  color: #FEFD8F;
  background-color:#FF6600;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

h2 {
    padding-top: 7px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    color: #FEFD8F;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a,  a:link {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color:#5E2F00;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fe6d00;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:focus {
  color: #fe6d00;
}

a:active {
  color: #fe6d00;
}

#outerWrapper {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto; 
  max-width: 1024px;
  min-width: 1024px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 1024px;
}
#outerWrapper #header {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#outerWrapper #header img {
  float: left;
}

#outerWrapper #contentWrapper .clearFloat {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
#outerWrapper #footer {
    padding: 11px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 52px;
    background-image:url(http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/images/footer.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
}

hr {
  width: 95%;
  height: 2px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
#navbarWrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 30px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px; /* Sets the margin properties for an element using shorthand notation (top, right, bottom, left) */
    padding: 0px; /* Sets the padding properties for an element using shorthand notation (top, right, bottom, left) */
    background-image: url(http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/includes/CSSMenuWriter/cssmw_images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
    }
-->
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
<!--

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: #000; 
  color: #000;
}
-->
</style>
<!--[if IE 5]>
<style type="text/css"> 
#outerWrapper #contentWrapper #leftColumn1 {
  width: 170px;
}
#outerWrapper #contentWrapper #rightColumn1 {
  width: 170px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css"> 
#outerWrapper #contentWrapper #content {
  zoom: 1;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<title>Dragboats.com - Photo Gallery - <?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/styles/full.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/styles/main.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../includes/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../includes/jcarousel/skins/tango/skin.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/UI/js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="../includes/UI/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
<!--
#specItems { margin:0 15px 0 15px; padding:0; overflow:auto; color:#222; background:#fff;}
#specItems ul {margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; white-space:nowrap; display:table-row;}
#specItems ul li {display:table-cell; padding:0 3px; background:#fff; vertical-align:top;}
#specItems ul li div {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 8px;
    border: thin solid #FF6D00;
}
#specItems ul li div p {margin:2px 4px 0 0; padding:0; font-size:11px; color: #000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; }

#sizes { margin:0 15px 0 15px; padding:0; overflow:auto; color:#222; background:#fff;}
#sizes ul {margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; white-space:nowrap; display:table-row;}
#sizes ul li {display:table-cell; padding:0 3px; background:#fff; vertical-align:top;}
#sizes ul li div { border: thin solid #FF6D00;}
#sizes ul li div p {margin:2px 4px 0 0; padding:0; font-size:11px; color: #F00; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; }
#sizes ul li .heading { text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; border-color: #FFF;}

#tip7-title { text-align: left; }

#tip7-title b { display: block; margin-right: 80px; }

#tip7-title span { float: right; }

.pictureThumb {
    float: right;
}
.thumbWrapper p {
    width: 130px;
}
.thumbWrapper {
    width: 140px;
    text-align: left;
}
.comment {
    background: #F3F3C1 url(../../images/comment_grad.gif) repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 273px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px #999966 solid;
    border-bottom: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 458px;
}

.comment-footer {
    background: url(../../images/comment_footer2.gif) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 273px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 38px;
    width: 483px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.feature_comment-footer {
      background: url(../../images/feature_comment_footer2.gif) no-repeat;
      background-position: 0 0;
      margin: 0 0 0 273px;
      padding: 5px 0 0 38px;    
      width: 483px;
      height: 35px;
      font-size: 11px;
}
.posterInfo {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #F60;
    font-style: italic;
}
.buttonHolder {
    width: 760px;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 9px; 
}
.buttonHolder img {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
-->
</style>
<script>
function fbs_click(u, t) {
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
    return false;}

//function formatTitle(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
 //   var titleSplit = title.split("~~");
//  var pathSplit = titleSplit[0].split("_");
//  return '<div id="tip7-title"><span><img src="../images/photo_comment.png" border="none" alt="Comment on this photo"/><a href="javascript:;" onclick="return fbs_click(\'http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/gallery/picture.php?imgID=' + titleSplit[0] + '\', \'Dragboats.com Photo\' )"><img src="../images/facebook_l.jpg" border="none" /></a><a href="javascript:;" onclick="addToCart(\'' + titleSplit[0] + '\')"><img src="../images/addToList.jpg" border="none" class="addToCart" alt="Add This Image To Your Cart"/></a></span>' + (titleSplit[1] && titleSplit[1].length ? '<b>' + titleSplit[1] + '</b>' : '' ) + 'Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' of ' + currentArray.length + '</div>';
//}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        //easing: 'BounceEaseOut',
        scroll: 6,
        animation: 800
    })

  //$('.infiniteCarousel').infiniteCarousel();

  $("a.pictureThumb").fancybox({
        'type'  : 'image',
        'padding' : '4',
        'overlayColor': '#000000',
        'width': 810,
        'height': 535,
        //'titlePosition' : 'outside',
        //'titleFormat'     : formatTitle,
        //'autoScale'       : true,
        //'autoDimension' : true,
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   300, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'hideOnOverlayClick' : true, 
        'hideOnContentClick': false 
    });
    $("a.calendar_sample").fancybox({
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'width' : 840,
        'height' : 640,
        'overlayColor': '#000000',
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'autoDimensions' :  'true',
        'speedIn'       :   300, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'hideOnOverlayClick' : false, 
        'hideOnContentClick': false, 
        'centerOnScroll': true
        //'onClosed': function() { parent.location.reload(true); ; } 
    });
    $("a.keychain_sample").fancybox({
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'width' : 660,
        'height' : 560,
        'overlayColor': '#000000',
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'autoDimensions' :  'true',
        'speedIn'       :   300, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'hideOnOverlayClick' : false, 
        'hideOnContentClick': false, 
        'centerOnScroll': true
        //'onClosed': function() { parent.location.reload(true); ; } 
    });
    $("a.vertcal_sample").fancybox({
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'width' : 445,
        'height' : 740,
        'overlayColor': '#000000',
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'autoDimensions' :  'true',
        'speedIn'       :   300, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'hideOnOverlayClick' : false, 
        'hideOnContentClick': false, 
        'centerOnScroll': true
        //'onClosed': function() { parent.location.reload(true); ; } 
    });
    $("a.pictureComment").fancybox({
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'width': 400,
        'height' : 280,
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'overlayColor': '#000000',
        'autoDimensions' :  'false',
        'speedIn'       :   300, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'hideOnOverlayClick' : false, 
        'hideOnContentClick': false, 
        'centerOnScroll': true,
        'onClosed': function() { parent.location.reload(true); } 
    });
    $("a.addToCart").fancybox({
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'width': 830,
        'height' : 520,
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'overlayColor': '#000000',
        'autoDimensions' :  'false',
        'speedIn'       :   300, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'hideOnOverlayClick' : false, 
        'hideOnContentClick': false, 
        'centerOnScroll': true
        //'onClosed': function() { parent.location.reload(true); ; } 
    });
    $(".showComment.hidden").live('click', function () { 
        //alert(this.id);
        //var adID = this.id.split('_');
        if($('#Comments').is(":visible")) {
            $('#Comments').fadeOut(600);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gallery/comments.php",
            data: "ID="+ this.id,
            success: function(r){
            //alert(r);
            //var allCommentInfo = r.split('_');
            var commentsHolder = 'Comments';
            var eachComment = r.split("**");
            var commentContainer = '';
            arLen = eachComment.length;
            //alert(arLen);
            if(arLen > 1){
            var commentDetails = new Array();
            commentContainer += '<div class="buttonHolder"><p><span id="comments-hide" style="cursor: pointer">CLOSE COMMENTS <img src="../images/close.png" title="Close Comments"></span></p></div>';
            for (var i=0; i<(arLen - 1); i++){
                commentDetails = eachComment[i].split("~");
                //alert(i);
                commentContainer += '<div class="comment">';
                commentContainer += "<p>" + commentDetails[2] + '</p></div>';               
                commentContainer += "<div class='comment-footer'>";
                commentContainer += '<div><p><span class="posterInfo">(Posted By: ' + commentDetails[0] + ') - </span>' + commentDetails[1] + '</p></div></div></div>'

            }
        if($('#Comments').is(":visible")) {
            $('#Comments').fadeOut(600, function() {
                $("#Comments").html(commentContainer);
                $("#Comments").slideDown(600, function() {
            $("#Comments").fadeIn(600);
            });
            });

        } else {
        $("#" + commentsHolder).html(commentContainer);
        $("#" + commentsHolder).slideDown(600);
        }
        //alert("#" + allCommentInfo[0] + "ReadText_" + allCommentInfo[1])
            }
        }
//End  Ajax Callback
});
//$(this).removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');
//End Main Callback
});
//End Document Ready
$('#comments-hide').live('click', function(){
    $("#Comments").slideUp(600);
    });
});
</script>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Tooltip" -->

<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <div id="header">
<img src="../images/r1c1.jpg" alt="" width="312" height="73" /><img src="../images/r1c2.jpg" alt="" width="397" height="73" /><img src="../images/r1c3.jpg" alt="" width="315" height="73" />
<img src="../images/r2c1.jpg" alt="" width="312" height="69" /><img src="../images/r2c2.jpg" alt="" width="397" height="69" /><img src="../images/r2c3.jpg" alt="" width="315" height="69" />
</div>
  <div id="navbarWrapper">
    <?php require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/CSSMenuWriter/cssmw/menu.php"); ?>
</div>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Content Area" -->
<div id="ContentHeader"></div>
<div id="contentWrapper">
  <div id="leftColumn1">
    <div class="columnHeadings">
      <h2>Photo Gallery Images - <?php echo $pageTitle; ?></h2>
      </div>
    <div class="fullWidthDiv">Below is a set of images from the gallery you chose.  To see additional images, click on the links at the bottom of this section to select the next group of images.</div>
    <div class="infiniteCarousel">
  <div class="wrap">
        <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
          <?php 
      do { ?>
          <li>
            <div class="thumbWrapper"><a class="pictureThumb" href="picture.php?imgID=<?php $pieces = explode('_', $row_rsPictures['PictureFile']); echo $pieces[0]."_".$pieces[1]."_".$pieces[2]; if ($pieces[3] == "NN"){ echo "_NN_".$pieces[4]."_".$pieces[5]; } else { echo "_".$pieces[3]."_".$pieces[4]; } ?>&thumb=Y">
              <img src="../images/gallery/<?php $raceYear = explode('_', $row_rsPictures['EventOverlay']); echo $raceYear[0]; ?>/<?php echo $row_rsPictures['EventOverlay']; ?>/thumb/<?php echo $row_rsPictures['PictureFile']; ?>.jpg" alt="FileName: <?php echo $row_rsPictures['PictureFile'];?>"></a><br />
<p>
<?php 
if($row_rsPictures['TotalComments'] > 0){
    if($row_rsPictures['TotalComments'] < 9){
    $commentCount = $row_rsPictures['TotalComments'];
        } else {
        $commentCount = "More";
        }
echo '<img src="../images/view_comment'.$commentCount.'.png" id="Comment_'.$row_rsPictures['PictureID'].'"  width="33" height="25" title="View Comments" alt="View Photo Comments" class="showComment hidden" style="cursor: pointer"/>';
} ?>
<a class="pictureComment" href="postComment.php?imgID=<?php echo $row_rsPictures['PictureID']; ?>&rf=gallery"><img src="../images/photo_comment.png" width="33" height="25" title="Comment On This Photo" alt="Comment On This Photo" /></a><a class="facebookShare" rel="nofollow" href="#" class="fb_share_button" onclick="return fbs_click('http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/gallery/picture.php?imgID=<?php $pieces = explode('_', $row_rsPictures['PictureFile']); echo $pieces[0]."_".$pieces[1]."_".$pieces[2]; if ($pieces[3] == "NN"){ echo "_NN_".$pieces[4]."_".$pieces[5]; } else { echo "_".$pieces[3]."_".$pieces[4]; } ?>', 'Dragboats.com Photo Gallery' )" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="../images/facebook.png" width="24" height="25" title="Share on Facebook" alt="Share on Facebook" /></a><a class="addToCart" href="adToCart.php?imgID=<?php echo $row_rsPictures['PictureFile'].'&dbID='.$row_rsPictures['PictureID']; ?>"><img src="../images/addToList.png" width="35" height="25" title="Add To Shopping List" alt="Add To Shopping List" /></a></p>
            </div>
            </li>
          <?php  
          } while ($row_rsPictures = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPictures));
          mysql_data_seek($rsPictures, 0);
          ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Comments" style="display: none"></div>
  <div style="text-align: center; padding-right: 15px; font-size: 10px">Gallery Image Sets: <?php
$TFM_Previous = $pageNum_rsPictures - 10;
if ($TFM_Previous >= 0) {
   printf('...<a href="'."%s?pageNum_rsPictures=%d%s", $currentPage, $TFM_Previous, $queryString_rsPictures.'">');
   echo "[Previous "."10"." sets] </a>...";
   //Basic-UltraDev Previous X pages SB
}
?>
  <?php
for ($i = $TFM_startLink; $i <= $TFM_endLink; $i++) {
  $TFM_LimitPageEndCount = $i -1;
  if($TFM_LimitPageEndCount != $pageNum_rsPictures) {
    printf('<a href="'."%s?pageNum_rsPictures=%d%s", $currentPage, $TFM_LimitPageEndCount, $queryString_rsPictures.' " class="pageLinkInActive">');
    echo "$i</a>";
  }else{
    echo "<span class='pageLinkActive'>$i</span>";
  }
if($i != $TFM_endLink) echo(" ");}
?>
  <?php
$TFM_Next = $pageNum_rsPictures + 10;
$TFM_Last = $totalPages_rsPictures+1;
if ($TFM_Next - 1 < $totalPages_rsPictures) { 
  printf('...<a href="'."%s?pageNum_rsPictures=%d%s", $currentPage, $TFM_Next, $queryString_rsPictures.'">');
    echo "[Next "."10"." of ".$TFM_Last." sets] </a>...";
}
?>
</div>
    <div class="columnFooters"> </div>
    <div class="columnHeadings">
      <h2>available print sizes</h2>
      </div>
    <div id="sizes"><ul>
      <li><div style="height: 120px; width: 180px;"><p>20x30<br />$65/ea</p></div></li>
      <li><div style="height: 96px; width: 120px;"><p>16x20<br />$45/ea</p></div></li>
      <li><div style="height: 78px; width: 114px;"><p>13x19<br />$40/ea</p></div></li>
      <li><div style="height: 72px; width: 108px;"><p>12x18<br />$30/ea</p></div></li>
      <li><div style="height: 66px; width: 84px;"><p>11x14<br />$25/ea</p></div></li>
      <li><div style="height: 48px; width: 60px;"><p>8x10<br />$15/ea</p></div></li>
      <li><div style="height: 30px; width: 42px;"><p style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 9px;">5x7<br />$10/ea</p></div></li>
      <li><div style="height: 24px; width: 36px;"><p style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 9px;">4x6<br />$5/ea</p></div></li>
      </ul></div>
    <div class="columnFooters"></div>
    <div class="columnHeadings">
      <h2>SPECIALTY ITEMS</h2>
      </div>
    <div class="fullWidthDiv">Click on the icon to see a sample and additional information or volume discounts</div>
<div id="specItems"><ul>
      <li><div><p>Digital File<br><img src="../images/gallery/digital_file.jpg" alt="Digital File" width="100" height="100" /><br>
        $125/ea</p></div></li>
      <li><div><p>Keychains<br />
            <a class="keychain_sample" href="keychainSample.php?imgID=<?php $pieces = explode('_', $sampleFile); echo $pieces[0]."_".$pieces[1]."_".$pieces[2]; if ($pieces[3] == "NN"){ echo "_NN_".$pieces[4]."_".$pieces[5]; } else { echo "_".$pieces[3]."_".$pieces[4]; } ?>"><img src="keychain.php?imgID=<?php $pieces = explode('_', $sampleFile); echo $pieces[0]."_".$pieces[1]."_".$pieces[2]; if ($pieces[3] == "NN"){ echo "_NN_".$pieces[4]."_".$pieces[5];; } else { echo "_".$pieces[3]."_".$pieces[4]; } ?>&thumb=Y" border="0"></a><br>$5/ea</p></div></li>
      <li>
        <div><p>Vertical<br />Calendars<br />
            <a class="vertcal_sample" href="vertCalender_sample.php?imgID=<?php $pieces = explode('_', $sampleFile); echo $pieces[0]."_".$pieces[1]."_".$pieces[2]; if ($pieces[3] == "NN"){ echo "_NN_".$pieces[4]."_".$pieces[5]; } else { echo "_".$pieces[3]."_".$pieces[4]; } ?>"><img src="vertCalender.php?imgID=<?php $pieces = explode('_', $sampleFile); echo $pieces[0]."_".$pieces[1]."_".$pieces[2]; if ($pieces[3] == "NN"){ echo "_NN_".$pieces[4]."_".$pieces[5]; } else { echo "_".$pieces[3]."_".$pieces[4]; } ?>&thumb=Y" border="0"></a><br>$35/ea</p></div></li>
           <li>
        <div><p>Wide<br />Calendars<br /><a class="calendar_sample" href="calender.php?imgID=<?php $pieces = explode('_', $sampleFile); echo $pieces[0]."_".$pieces[1]."_".$pieces[2]; if ($pieces[3] == "NN"){ echo "_NN_".$pieces[4]."_".$pieces[5]; } else { echo "_".$pieces[3]."_".$pieces[4]; } ?>"><img src="calenderSample.php?imgID=<?php $pieces = explode('_', $sampleFile); echo $pieces[0]."_".$pieces[1]."_".$pieces[2]; if ($pieces[3] == "NN"){ echo "_NN_".$pieces[4]."_".$pieces[5]; } else { echo "_".$pieces[3]."_".$pieces[4]; } ?>&thumb=Y" border="0"></a><br>$35/ea</p></div></li>
      <li><div><p>Mousepads<br /><img src="mousepad.php?imgID=<?php $pieces = explode('_', $sampleFile); echo $pieces[0]."_".$pieces[1]."_".$pieces[2]; if ($pieces[3] == "NN"){ echo "_NN_".$pieces[4]."_".$pieces[5];; } else { echo "_".$pieces[3]."_".$pieces[4]; } ?>&thumb=Y" border="0"><br>$17.50/ea</p></div></li>
</ul>
</div>
    <div class="columnFooters"></div>
    </div>    
  <br class="clearFloat" />
</div>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<div id="ContentFooter"></div>
<div id="footer"><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/<?php if(isset($_SESSION['svUserID'])) { echo "logout"; } else { echo "login"; } ?>.php"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['svUserID'])) { echo "LOGOUT"; } else { echo "LOGIN"; } ?></a> || <a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>">HOME</a> || <a href="../classifieds/main.php">CLASSIFIEDS</a> || <a href="../cart/view_cart.php">CART</a> || <a href="main.php">PICTURES</a> || <a href="../merch/main.php">MERCHANDISE</a> || <a href="../video/main.php">VIDEOS</a> || <a href="../video">SCHEDULES</a> || <a href="../results.php">RESULTS</a> || <a href="../downloads.php">DOWNLOADS</a> || <a href="../rides/main.php">RIDES</a> || <a href="../rides">SERVICES</a> || <a href="../contact.php">CONTACT US</a><br />
SITE CREATED AND MAINTAINED BY <a href="http://www.finishline-productions.com" target="_blank">FINISHLINE PRODUCTIONS</a> - COPYRIGHT 1997 - <?php echo date("Y"); ?> - <a href="../docs/privacy.php">PRIVACY POLICY</a> - <a href="../docs/usage.php">TERMS OF USE</a> - <a href="../docs/returns.php">RETURN POLICY</a></div>
</div>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($rsPictures);
?>
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: What´s with the `Page Load Error`?

Comment: @jeroen  I guess it is not an error, just doesn't load correctly.  I don't want it to show the thumbnails in the vertical alignment, I want the to show once all of the loading is done.  Load the page on a slow connection, and you will know what I mean

Comment: @dtbarne  I might not be as knowledgeable as you are at this.....and yes I have done a lot of debugging to make all of it work.  I certainly don't expect people to do ALL the work for me.  A starting point was all I was looking for and some possible solutions.  I wouldn't consider that ALL the work.  I posted the ENTIRE code, because usually when I post things, they want to see the ENTIRE code, to find a solution.

Comment: @dragboatrandy I've changed the title to match your question.

Comment: @jeroen  Thank you.  That is actually a much better title.

Comment: @Joris Meys  I apologize for posting so much code.  I thought that an overview of the entire page was necessary to find a solution.  I will not post the entire code next time.  As far as doing my homework, I have done a tremendous amount of work on this page without asking a single question on here about it.  I only did that because there is a huge community of those who know more than I.  If you have a car problem, and I knew how to fix it, I would gladly help.  I did do my homework, it was a problem that I didn't know how to fix....

Comment: @Joris Meys As far as exceptence rate, maybe I just don't know how to work this site correctly, but when I have posted a question that I got the answer for, I excepted it.  There have been many times, I got one answer, and replied, but never received any other information on the fix.  I thought this was a helping community.  Don't worry, I don't really want YOUR help, there are plenty of very giving people who really don't mind helping.

Comment: @dragboatrandy I didn't want to be rude, just wanted to point out some general policies here on SO. With 'doing your homework' I meant providing a minimal reproducible example. Your question was flagged and has 5 minus votes. I only wanted to explain why this was and how to avoid that in the future. Consider that my help. I could also not bother at all... PS : english is not my mother tongue, so forgive me for not knowing all the subtilities. I really tried to be polite.

Comment: @Joris Meys  I apologize for my stern reply.  I wasn't sure how to make a minimal reproducible problem that could be done in any other way than the way I did it.  Thank you for your help.  I don't understand what Minus votes and flagged meant so I am sorry for the problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you are using jquery, just add this somewhere in a scripts section:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#outerWrapper").hide();
});
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#outerWrapper").show();
});
```

You could of course set `#outerWrapper` to `display:none` in the css, but then you´ll never see anything in a browser where javascript is disabled.

Comment: @jeroen  I tried that, and it just seems to break the script.  No it is throwing Javascript errors.

Comment: There was a missing `);` from the end of the script which has been added now. That should clear up your javascript errors.

Comment: You might want to consider hiding into overflow (width=1, height=1 overflow=hidden) instead of a full `display:none`; some browsers might not load contents in hidden elements.

Comment: @Blair McMillan  For some reason, it does the exact same thing as it did before.  It shows the content for a second then hides it, then shows the page fully rendered.

Comment: @Blair McMillan Thanks, I missed that one @Christian Sciberras Good point, that seems better. I guess there are several solutions you could try as long as you use the two functions (DOM ready and everything loaded).

Comment: @dragboatrandy That's because at initial page-load the content is not yet hidden. Like I said, you can set the div to `display:none` in css but that breaks if javascript is disabled. It will get a better result if javascript is enabled though.

Comment: @jeroen If there was a badge 'Lord of Patience', you have earned it by now. Twice...

Comment: @joreon  I went forward with the #outerWrapper: hidden option, and did a check for javascript enabled.  Seems the best solution for me at this point.  I need to get this thing done.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @joreon  I used the hidden option, and it had some adverse affects, it only loaded a portion of the thumbnails, perhaps that is the overflow issue that someone spoke of earlier.  I have since just left it the way it was and I will just deal with it.  Thank you for you help!

Comment: @Christian Sciberras found a solution.  Using Christian's information above and @jeroen info, came up with this: CSS:.infiniteCarousel {
    width: 1px;
 height: 1px;
 /* width: 880px; */
 overflow: hidden;
    /* padding: 20px 40px; */
}
.loading{
    height: 160px;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('../images/35.gif');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
}JS:$(window).load(function() {
  $(".loading").delay(800).hide(0, function() {;
  $(".infiniteCarousel").animate({ width: 965, height: 160}, 400);
  });
});  Works pretty much like I wanted.  Thanks for the help